# Get the name of the file a storyboard is from in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I have a storyboard file and I want to reference the name of the file that the storyboard is implemented in so that I can load a configuration file of the same base name.

Here is an example that is in a file called `scene001.lua`

```
-- Called when the scene's view does not exist:
function scene:createScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view

    local json = require("json")
    -- load the book definition file
    local contents = textFromFile("scene001.json")
    local page = json.decode(contents)
    image = buildPage(page)
    screenGroup:insert(image)
    image.touch = onSceneTouch
end
```

As you can see I have to hard code the `"scene001.json"`. I want to load a configuration file of the with the same name as the current storyboard, how can I do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a better more official way of doing this without all the regex sillyness needed to parse the path. Of the potential performance implications of using `debug.getinfo()`.

[`storyboard.getCurrentSceneName()`](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/storyboard/getCurrentSceneName.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `debug` library, specifically the function `debug.getinfo`, to retrieve information about the current file name. With a simple pattern, you can then replace the `.lua` extension with `.json` to open your custom file.

```
print( debug.getinfo(1,"S").short_src ) --> /path/to/scene001.lua.
```